# SQL Query to get data from each column

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I have multiple columns in a table

One column may contain the name of the state (US), another column contains the speciality

Here is some sample data (there could be more than one C# in NY and may also exist in other states)

```
C# NY
C# NJ
C# WA
C# CA
C# NY
C# NY
Java NY
Java NJ
Java IL
```

Basically I want to get an output that has

```
C# 100 (sum of all states that have C#)
Java 85 (sum of all states that have Java)
```

and I would like to get

```
State  Total Speciality
NY     150   C# 
NY     100   C++
```

I am using SQLite3 as my DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SqlLite should have GROUP BY and COUNT. You may try:

```
SELECT Speciality, COUNT(State) AS Total
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY Speciality
```

and

```
SELECT State, Speciality, COUNT(*)  AS Total
FROM YourTable 
GROUP BY State, Speciality
```